# Why is Count increasing, Closure issue

Tags: javascript, node.js

Basically what I am trying to do here is , do nmap scan on 7 machines using nmap/nodejs and then when the response comeback, I am writing it to the client page.
When I run this it works fine.Its using closure, to wrap the variable count, so every callback gets count = 0.

Now what I don't understand is, why is the value of count increasing from 1 to 7 as per the console.log.  As per my understanding, every method gets a count.

Can someone please explain why this is

Output from nodejs  ::

```
server is listening
8.8.8.1
8.8.8.2
8.8.8.3
8.8.8.4
8.8.8.5
8.8.8.6
8.8.8.8
count = 1
count = 2
count = 3
count = 4
count = 5
count = 6
count = 7
ending the response
```

Code ::

```
var http = require('http');
var cb = function(httpRequest, httpResponse){
var count = 0;

var ips = [];
ips.push('8.8.8.1');
ips.push('8.8.8.2');
ips.push('8.8.8.3');
ips.push('8.8.8.4');
ips.push('8.8.8.5');
ips.push('8.8.8.6');
ips.push('8.8.8.8');

var exec = require('child_process').exec;
for(var i =0; i< ips.length ; i++)
{
    exec('nmap.exe -v ' + ips[i], function(error, stdout, stderr) {

        if(error)
        {
            httpResponse.write(stderr);
            httpResponse.write("</br>")
            httpResponse.write("*************************");
        }
        else
        {
            httpResponse.write(stdout);
            httpResponse.write("</br>")
            httpResponse.write("*************************");
        }

        count = count + 1;

        console.log('count = ' +  count);

        if (count === 7)
        {
            console.log('ending the response');
            httpResponse.end();
        }

    });

    console.log(ips[i]);
}
}

var server = http.createServer(cb);

server.listen(8080, function(){
    console.log('server is listening');
});
```

-Thanks

Comment: What do you mean, "*every callback gets `count = 0`*"?

Comment: `count` is declared at the top level scope of your example. If it were not, it would be put onto the global scope upon the first occurrence of `count = count + 1`. The closure (the exec callback) refers in either case to a count variable up the scope chain. It is therefore behaving as expected. Also, perhaps you didn't notice there are only seven IP addresses because it skips from .6 to .8. That's why the count only goes to seven.

Comment: Well what I was thinking is ... the callback function when nmap.exe completes will  have a value of count = 0, from the upper scope.

Comment: My understanding is wrong in this case , I thought that because of closure, every callback will get its own count  but since its using the global scope count, it working as expected. makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `count` is declared in the global space in line 3 of your code, each loop is increasing the outer count by one. This will not cause your count to reset. If you want to instantiate a new count variable, you need to declare `var count` within your loop instead.

Answer (score 0):

`count` is increasing from 1 to 7 because you're increasing it by `1` on every iteration of the loop which loops over the array of `ips` which contain 7 elements. Every new request gets the count reset to 0. Every request you are iterating through all 7 elements.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are wanting to use closures on the `count` variable. However, you did not implement closures on the count variable. In order to pass a copy of `count` to each asynchronous function you should wrap the corresponding blocks of code in a function call that takes `count` as an argument. For Example:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
for(var i =0; i< ips.length ; i++)
{
(function(count) { //Start of closure function storing a local copy of count
exec('nmap -v ' + ips[i], function(error, stdout, stderr) {

    if(error)
    {
        httpResponse.write(stderr);
        httpResponse.write("</br>")
        httpResponse.write("*************************");
    }
    else
    {
        httpResponse.write(stdout);
        httpResponse.write("</br>")
        httpResponse.write("*************************");
    }

    count = count + 1;

    console.log('count = ' +  count);

    if (count === 7)
    {
        console.log('ending the response');
        httpResponse.end();
    }

});
})(count); // end of closure function
console.log(ips[i]);
}
```

Running this will get you the output:

```
count = 1
count = 1
count = 1
count = 1
count = 1
count = 1
count = 1
```